# How to send bulk sms on whatsapp

Tags: python, whatsapp

I want to send bulk SMS on WhatsApp without creating broadcast list.

For that reason, I found **pywhatsapp** package in python but it requires WhatsApp client registration through **yowsup-cli**.

So I've run **`yowsup-cli registration -r sms -C 00 -p 000000000000`** which resulted in the error below:

> INFO:yowsup.common.http.warequest:{"status":"fail","reason":"old_version"}
>
> status: fail reason: old_version

What did I do wrong and how can I resolve this?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/issues/1738 I just searched "yowsup-cli old_version" in Google.

Comment: Update your version of yowsup-cli?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get clearly points out the nature of the challenge you are facing: it has to do with your version of **`yowsup-cli`**; ***it's an old version***.

It means that your project requires a version of **`yowsup-cli`** higher than what you currently have so as to work effectively as require.

What you need to do so as to resolve it is: to update your **`yowsup-cli`** application to a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the http headers that are sent to whatsapp servers, these are found in env/env.py
The name of headers are manually provided, therefore due to new updates whatsapp servers only serve or authenticate to updated devices which is identified with their http/https/etc headers, in this case you need to update some constants in the above file(env/env.py) in your yowsup folder.

Comment: Thanks Cioslous Kumar, so may i know which constants i should change?

Comment: Use this fork instead, it has already updated values. 
https://github.com/jlguardi/yowsup